# reporting drop result : false android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-gridview

I want to save captured image and set them to **gridview** then user can drag & drop to change the position of captured image, that is first image, but I'm very new to use drag & drop function, can you explain it?

How to modify this code ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button btPhoto, btSave;
private GridView gridview;
private File imgFile;
private String path;
private ArrayList<File> List_File;
private static final int imageCode = 100;
private Context context;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btPhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btPhoto);
    btSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_save);
    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);


    path = "/TongFolder/";
    context = this;
    List_File = new ArrayList<File>();
    File imgDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+path);
    imgDir.mkdirs();
    boolean check = imgDir.isDirectory();
    if(check == true){
    btPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            capture();

        }
    });
    }else{
        System.out.println("not create");
    }
 }


public void capture(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    imgFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+path, 
            "img_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
    startActivityForResult(intent, imageCode);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

    if(requestCode == imageCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        //add path to arrayList
        List_File.add(imgFile);
        for (File file : List_File) {
            String showPath = file.getPath();
            System.out.println(showPath);
        }

        gridview.setAdapter(new gridViewAdapter(context, List_File));
        if(gridview != null){
            DragDrop();
        }

    }

}

public void DragDrop(){

    gridview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            DragShadow dragshadow = new DragShadow(v);

            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");

            v.startDrag(data, dragshadow, v, 0);

            return true;

        }
    }); 

}

OnDragListener dragListener = new OnDragListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();

        switch (action) {

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            Log.i("drag event", "entered");
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            Log.i("drag event", "exited");
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

            Log.i("drag event", "drop");

            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
};

private class DragShadow extends View.DragShadowBuilder{

    ColorDrawable boxShadow;

    public DragShadow(View view) {
        super(view);
        boxShadow = new ColorDrawable(Color.LTGRAY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {

        boxShadow.draw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point shadowSize,
            Point shadowTouchPoint) {

        View v = getView();
        int height = (int)v.getHeight();
        int weight = (int)v.getWidth();

        boxShadow.setBounds(0, 0, weight, height);
        shadowSize.set(weight, height);
        shadowTouchPoint.set((int)weight/2, (int)height/2);

    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```